# How solve these error using tomcat server in eclipse for deploy jsp page?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat5.5

HTTP Status 404 - /JspTest1/

---

type Status report

message /Projectname/

description The requested resource (/Projectname/) is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the directory structure and the files (like web.xml etc ) are correct.
Also recheck the path (URL) that you are using in your browser to access your app.
Check the logs in tomcat folder for more detailed explaination of error. Also try to put you app in webapps and then run in tomcat directly

Comment: it run in tomcat seperately but how it run in eclipse?